# How do I add a local IP address to the list of trusted domains in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

Currently, localhost is on the list of trusted domains in Oauth settings in my Firebase app. However, I cannot add the local IP address of my machine to this list, it says something along the lines of "provide a real address". I need it so that I can test the app on a mobile phone, I can't just type "localhost:3000" in the address bar on the phone, it's only possible with "192.168.2.103:3000" which is, again, not on the list.

Comment: are you adding the port to the IP address while trying to add the domain? Can you post an image of the error  you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't allow for you to add local IP addresses with enter, and will show your message ("A valid domain name is required (e.g. 'myapp.com')." but actually clicking on the add button will push the request through.